# How to get two text inputs to show in one message with OnClickListener in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, onclicklistener

I have two text input fields and a button. I managed to implement that, when both textfields are filled and I click the button, a message showing the input from the first text field is showing.

What I would like to do is to implement that when both textfields are filled and I click the button, a message showing the input from the both text fields (in one message) is showing.

Could anyone help me to do that?/ Has anyone done something similar? Thank you in advance!

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    
    val autotextView
            = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.autoTextViewStart)
    val autotextViewZiel
            = findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.autoTextViewZiel)


    // Get the array of languages
    val languages
            = resources.getStringArray(R.array.Languages)
    // Create adapter and add in AutoCompleteTextView
    val adapter
            = ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, languages)
    autotextView.setAdapter(adapter)
    autotextViewZiel.setAdapter(adapter)


    val button
            = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn); if (button != null)
    {
        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val enteredText = autotextView.getText()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, enteredText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to concatenate 2 strings in Kotlin, there are various ways. Please find them [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-idioms-strings.html) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/concatenate-strings). Simple one you can do as follows:

```
button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val enteredText = autotextView.getText() + "  " +autotextViewZiel.getText()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, enteredText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
```